# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core: No applicable method 'ArrayLength' exists in type

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, dynamic, expression

When parsing the expression I get the error “No applicable method 'ArrayLength' exists in type 'Product'”.

Here's the expression itself:

```
var experession = "p => (p.MarketingProduct!= null) AndAlso (ArrayLength(p.MarketingProduct.Categories) > 0)"
var result = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Product, bool>(new ParsingConfig(), true, experession);
```

Is there any built-in solution to this problem in the System.Linq.Dynamic.Core library?

var result = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Product, bool>(new ParsingConfig(), true, experession);

Answer (score 1):

The error message you're encountering,

> No applicable method 'ArrayLength' exists in type 'Product'

suggests that the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library does not recognize the `ArrayLength` function in the expression you're trying to parse. This library primarily works with standard `.NET` methods and functions, and ArrayLength is not a built-in function in `C#` or `.NET`.

If you want to check the length of an array or collection in a dynamic `LINQ` expression, you can use the `Count()` method instead. Here's how you can modify your expression:

```
var expression = "p => (p.MarketingProduct != null) && (p.MarketingProduct.Categories != null && p.MarketingProduct.Categories.Count() > 0)";
var result = DynamicExpressionParser.ParseLambda<Product, bool>(new ParsingConfig(), true, expression);
```

In this modified expression, we check if `MarketingProduct` is not null and if `MarketingProduct`. `Categories` is not null. Then, we use the `Count()` method to check if there are any elements in the `Categories` collection.

This should work with the `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` library and help you avoid the error you mentioned.

Comment: ArrayLength is obtained when expression is compiled. This is a built-in c# mechanism.
`
Expression = p => p.MarketingProduct != null 
                                                       && p.MarketingProduct.Categories != null
                                                       && p.MarketingProduct.Categories.Length > 0

if (expression != null)
                    products = products.Where(expression.Compile()).ToArray();
`